# Will two albums duplicate pictures in Photos.app?

Tags: photos.app

I am trying to put together several albums and some of them have a picture from another album. For example a parties album and a birthday 2015 album or a granddaughters 2015 album.  So how do I put the same photos in these 3 albums, and are they duplicated or just cross referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the photo from one album to another. The photo will be added to the second album and not removed from the first. Only one master copy of the photo is kept and is cross-referenced throughout the library regardless of where it is used.

Comment: WOW!!! That was quick . Thanks so much. I am on a deadline for a party and want to have an album to use as a screensaver to surprise my family.

Comment: oops. Another question. How do I have two albums open.Sorry for stupid questions. I am new to all of this. I go to photos and open the album, but then when I open the other album, the first is replaced with this one.  So how do i get them 'side by side' to drag and drop?  Thanks again

Comment: @Orchard I use the sidebar for this kind of thing, accessible from View → Show Sidebar.